# AudioUnitRender and ExtAudioFileWrite error -50 in Swift: Trying to convert MIDI to Audio File

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiobuffer, mikmidi

I'm trying to convert a MIDI file to an Audio File (.m4a) in Swift.

Right now I'm using [MIKMIDI](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI) as a tool to sequence and playback MIDI files, however it does not include the ability to save the playback into a file. MIKMID's creator outlines the process to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342278/5278422). In an attempt to capture and save the output to an audio file, I've followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15361251/5278422) to try and replace the MIKMIDI Graph's RemoteIO node with a GeneralIO node in Swift. When I try to save the output to a file using AudioUnitRender and ExtAudioFileWrite, they both return error -50 (kAudio_ParamError).

```
    var channels = 2
    var buffFrames = 512
    var bufferList = AudioBufferList.allocate(maximumBuffers: 1)

         for i in 0...bufferList.count-1{

               var buffer = AudioBuffer()
               buffer.mNumberChannels = 2
               buffer.mDataByteSize = UInt32(buffFrames*sizeofValue(AudioUnitSampleType))
               buffer.mData = calloc(buffFrames, sizeofValue(AudioUnitSampleType))

               bufferList[i] = buffer

               result = AudioUnitRender(generalIOAudioUnit, &flags, &inTimeStamp, busNum, UInt32(buffFrames), bufferList.unsafeMutablePointer)
               inTimeStamp.mSampleTime += 1

               result = ExtAudioFileWrite(extAudioFile, UInt32(buffFrames), bufferList.unsafeMutablePointer)

         }
```

What is causing error -50, and how can I resolve it to render the MIDI (*offline*) to .m4a files?

**UPDATE**: I have resolved the ExtAudioFileWrite error -50 by changing mNumberChannels and channels to = 1. Now I get a one second audio file with noise. AudioUnitRender still returns error -50.

Comment: do you have a sample project?

Comment: Sure, I just created one: [link](https://github.com/bamboostick/MIKMIDI-To-Audio-File-Attempt-Example-Project/tree/master). Let me know how it works out!

Comment: cool! but the soundfont file is missing. as is the podfile.

Comment: Whoops! Okay I've added them both now. Just run _pod install_ to add the cocoapods to the project and it should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. your `AudioBufferList` doesn't agree with the client format, try

   ```
   let bufferList = AudioBufferList.allocate(maximumBuffers: Int(clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame))
   ```
2. you're replacing the wrong node from the `AUGraph`, and connecting the remaining node to itself, resulting in an infinite loop on `AudioUnitRender`.

But the main problem is that you are not implementing the solution that the [author suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342278/5278422). You wish that you could call `AudioUnitRender` with sample timestamps, faster than realtime, but the author said no, you'll have to manually convert sample time to hosttime and implement the better part of a midi player if you want that.

So you could do that (sounds hard), or [file a feature request](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI/issues/new), or maybe record to file in realtime as you listen to the music by adding a render notification to the graph's remote IO audio unit with `AudioUnitAddRenderNotify` and writing the samples during the `kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender` phase.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the incredible support. I would have spent weeks on this! I just tried to adjust the AudioBufferList channels, and I received a kAudioUnitErr_Uninitialized err. To fix that, I tried AudioUnitInitialize(), however that lead me back to the same -50 error I had. In my full project I need to render long, programatically created midi sequences and doing it in real time too long. For now, I'll file a feature request to MIKMIDI. If I were to create a player, would [this](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-2-avfoundation-to-play-audio-or-midi/) be a good starting point?

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I've added a feature request here: https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI/issues/164

Comment: As noted in the issue linked by @bamboostickk, I've added an example project to MIKMIDI that demonstrates how to do what the OP was asking to do. See `Examples/macOS/MIDI To Audio` in MIKMIDI.